# get list users with some data from another table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have table ( users )
and I have another table let's say (books)

users table :

### Id | Username

1  :: john

2  :: doe

books table:

### id  | book_title  | user_id(user who own this book)

1   :: book1       :: 2

2   :: book2       :: 2

3   :: book3       :: 2

4   :: book4       :: 1

5   :: book5       :: 1

Now , how can I get list of users and get how many books every user have

like this :

- john ( 2 books )
- doe  ( 3 books )

---

I use codeigniter framework ..

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your second question:

I just had to do this for some of my own analytics:

```
SELECT users.* , 

   (SELECT COUNT( 1 ) 
    FROM books
    WHERE user_id = users.id) 
    AS  "Number of Books",

   (SELECT COUNT( 1 )
    FROM files
    WHERE user_id = users.id)
    AS  "Number of Files"

FROM users
```

If you have to do this frequently, you might want to figure out how to do this using multiple joins which are more efficient than subqueries.

Comment: thank you very much , I tried hundreds of time to do that but I did not find it by myself , thank you again , it's work perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this SQL database? Couldn't you use SQL query to get what you want?:

```
SELECT Username, COUNT(books) AS how_many_books FROM users JOIN books ON users.id=books.user_id GROUP BY Username
```

Comment: thank you very much Jacek , it's work ! .. I have another question if it is possible , how can I get also how many files ( from files table ) so I can get list like this : jonhn ( 4 books & 9 files ) in same way about books tabl ?  thanks again jacek

Answer (score 0):

While looping through your output of users, you'll want to make another call to the DB within the loop with something like `$this->db->count_all_results();` with a `where` line to select the userID. Sorry for not explaining too well, but if you understand the logic of it, you'll be fine.

BUT this is my explanation without too much knowledge of `JOIN`, as seen above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CI's Active Record framework, it would be something like this:

```
$this->db->select('Users.Username, COUNT(Book.Id) AS user_book_count');
$this->db->from('Users');
$this->db->join('Books', 'Users.Id = Books.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('Users.Id');

$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $users[] = $row->username . '(' . $row->user_book_count . ')';
    }
    return $users;
}
```